# Using a field name as another field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection that's structure is somewhat similar to the following:-

**Initial:**

```json
{alphabets1:
     [{a:value11},
      {b:value12},
      {c:value13},...]
},
{alphabets2:
     [{a:value21},
      {b:value22},
      {c:value23},...]
}
```

I need to get the following information from the above collection:

**Required:**

```json
{alphabets1:value11+value12+value13...},
{alphabets2:value21+value22+value23...}
```

To get the above structure above, I have to modify the documents structure in the array to the following:

```json
{alphabets1:[{fieldName:a,value:value11},
             {fieldName:b,value:value12},
             {fieldName:c,value:value13},...]},
{alphabets2:[{fieldName:a,value:value21},
             {fieldName:b,value:value22},
             {fieldName:c,value:value23},...]},
```

and use `$group` aggregate.

And for this, I have to access the field name, but I couldn't find a way to do it in mongodb and I was wondering if there are any other ways to get the **Required** format from the **Initial** document structure.

Comment: Try using `$objectToArray`